# How LeakCanary android library manages to install another android application from the application which uses this library?

Tags: android

I need to launch "my hypothetical application" in order to show certain events which have been tracked on the application which has installed my "hypothetical library". But I can’t figure out how to achieve it, and the only library which perform this kind of behaviour -as far as I know, is [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary).

Any thoughts will be appreciate.

Comment: "How LeakCanary android library manages to install another android application from the application which uses this library?" -- what evidence do you have that LeakCanary "manages to install another android application from the application which uses this library".

Comment: When I launch my application from Android Studio using LeakCanary  another application with the logo of LeakCanary shows on the specific device. But It seems that I missed something. Am I right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think `LeakCanary` installs separate apk which will work as exported service and allow applications to be bound to. I went through the flow how it works, when you call `LeakCanary.install(context)` it starts `HeapAnalyzerService` which is a `Service` which depends on application lifecycle callbacks.

What you see as separate application is the `DisplayLeakActivity` which has it's intent declared as:

```
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
```

Any activity with `MAIN` action and category `LAUNCHER` will be placed in the launcher.

Comment: Thanks Nikola. I did not know it was possible to do so.

Comment: Hello, @Nikola I have created a shortcut for the same thing but shortcut doesn't show in the app list and I have also searched for bound service which will help to create another app launcher with different intent. Can you help me with this as an answer which shows how to use bound service for it? Thanks